# how to rsync from a host computer to docker container using docker cp

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run following:

1. start a container in background

`docker run -dit -p 8090:80 --name container repository:dockerfile bash`

2. I want to exclude sub directory `/data` from `/test`

`docker cp /Users/$USER/test container:/test`

3. I thought of using rsync for this
   `docker exec rsync -avP  --exclude /Users/$USER/test/data /Users/$USER/test/ container:/test/`

I get below error:

```
rsync: Failed to exec ssh: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [sender=3.1.0]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226)
[sender=3.1.0]
```

How do I rsync from host to container?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Map the host directory first, into the container:

```
docker run -v /Users/$USER/test:/temp-test -dit -p 8090:80 --name container repository:dockerfile bash
```

Then use the rsync as follows:

```
docker exec container rsync -avP --exclude /temp-test/data /temp-test/ /test/
```

Answer (score 7):

**The way to use rsync to copy files into a Docker container**

Make sure your Docker container has rsync installed, and define this alias:

```
alias drsync="rsync -e 'docker exec -i'"
```

Now, you can use rsync with containers as if they are remote machines:

```
drsync -av /source/ container:/destination/
```

Comment: protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(178) [sender=3.1.3]

Should I add bin/bash following?

Comment: How would you do this if the container is running on a remote server? Let's say, I use this command, to transfer files directly to the server: 

"rsync -avP /source/ user@remote_server:/destination"

and the container name is "container".

Comment: This is great! I would put more emphasis on **"Make sure your Docker container has rsync installed"**. Without that, you'll get the cryptic error: ["protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?"](https://serverfault.com/a/803499/117206)

Answer (score 4):

When you run `docker exec rsync [...]` you execute the `rsync` command in your container. The path `/Users/$USER/test/` corresponds to a directory on you host system, so rsync has a hard time finding it in your container.

There are basically two ways to use `rsync` to transfer files into a container:

1. You can install an ssh server on you host system and use rsync to connect from within your container to the host system *from the outside*. If you have a running ssh server on you host and the host is reachable under the name `host` you can do

   ```
   docker exec rsync -avP --exclude /Users/$USER/test/data host:/Users/$USER/test /test
   ```
2. You can install an ssh server inside the container and use rsync on your host system to connect to the container *from the outside*. I assume your container is reachable under the name `container`, then you can do

   ```
   rsync avP --exclude /Users/$USER/test/data /Users/$USER/test container:/test
   ```

   In this case you have to make sure that the ssh port (default is 22) is published by the docker daemon.

Comment: rsync has a server mode, you dont need ssh for that

Comment: You have to worry about `protocol version mismatch` if you don't install ssh. I ended up installing ssh too.

Answer (score 1):

This should mirror the command you attempted in the OP...

```
rsync -avPe 'docker exec -i' --exclude /Users/$USER/test/data /Users/$USER/test/ container:/test/
```

It works similarly to get files out of the container.

Credit to https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/13660#issuecomment-165500701

Answer (score 0):

The

> rsync: Failed to exec ssh: No such file or directory (2)

is caused because ssh is not installed for you container.
You install it manual or add it to your requirements file to install it automaticly.