# Access data inside volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I successfully ran a bind-mount for my blog, however I think that a managed volume would be a better choice instead of bind-mount, the question is, if I need to edit the theme through SFTP or vim or simply add some files to the volume, how do I do that? Right now the bind-mount allows me to edit the files, but how would I add/edit files on the volume or if I wanted later to get those files out?

For example: `docker volume create --name test-volume`

How can I add/edit data there or access via SFTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As says the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/):

> Volumes are stored in a part of the host filesystem which is managed by Docker (/var/lib/docker/volumes/ on Linux). Non-Docker processes should not modify this part of the filesystem.

So the idea is to set up a new container, that bind the working directory as well as mounts a volume, and then manage files in them.

For example, lets say your working dir is `/app`:

```
docker run \
  -v $PROJECT:/tmp/project
  -v test-volume:/app \
  alpine \
  /bin/sh -c "cp /tmp/project/* /app"
```

Sync tools can be used, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723891/how-to-rsync-from-a-host-computer-to-docker-container-using-docker-cp).

To manage data of your volume through container itself via SFTP, you need to make sure that image you are using supports SSH connections and map a 22 port, more info you could find [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/6fa7/creating-a-ssh-and-sftp-server-with-docker-compose).

Comment: No, that's a bind-mount volume what you are talking about. I'm saying a managed volume