# Docker react app, webpack compiles but browser doesn't refresh after editing and saving

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, docker-compose, react-scripts

I am working on a project that includes react as frontend technology. Python Django is used for backend and both of them dockerized by a docker-compose file and Dockerfiles. When I try to edit and save index.html or App.js file, nothing happened. Docker container terminal and browser stayed still, despite app's files are mounted correctly in docker-compose file.

When I look up for the solution to this case on SO and other websites, all of the suggestions were made towards to environment variables like CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING, WATCPACK_POLLING and FAST_REFRESH.

In those websites, WATCHPACK_POLLING was suggested to use instead of CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING due to using react-scripts version 5.0.1 in my project. So I set WATCHPACK_POLLING=true in environment variable and tried again.

This time webpack compiles with this message in terminal:

```
frontend-app-1       | Compiling...
frontend-app-1       | Compiled successfully!
frontend-app-1       | webpack compiled successfully
```

But after compiling successfully nothing happens, browser still does not refresh. I've tried to set FAST_REFRESH=false to enable hot reloading but nothing changed.

I've mixed up old and new solutions and using CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING and WATCHPACK_POLLING at the same time. This time after editing and saving compiling has done again and browser refreshes but with a slight issue. Browser refresh process cant catch up the compiling and these two process are being done unsynchronized.

So when I change the website title from "React App" to "React" and save it, compilation starts and broser refreshes. Browser still displays "React App" title. After that when I edit index file again to change title from "React" to "Test", refreshed browser diplays title "React". Refreshment is following at least one step behind like this.

Essentially my problem is after edit and save in a dockerized react app, webpack compiles successfully but browser does not refresh.

How can I solve this problem?

Edit: I've tried FAST_REFRESH with these two variables and nothing changed.

Comment: Any suggestions? Connections between Docker container and my machine via ports and volumes are working correctly I guess, is there any environment variables  that can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you editing source code on host machine? If yes then do you have a bind mount of the source code folder or file to the container?
2. Please try different `node` versions. I had the same issue recently and got it resolved after taking an image with different `node` version.
3. If previous options don't work then you can setup directory synchronization between host and container. See [how to rsync from a host computer to docker container using docker cp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723891/how-to-rsync-from-a-host-computer-to-docker-container-using-docker-cp) for details.

Comment: 1. Yes I edit on host machine and I have a bind mount, I can say that because my editings effect page when I manually refresh the page. 2. If I use lower version there will be lots of deprecations, can I achieve auto refresh without lowering node version?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to find what is causing the issue and I managed to fix it only by switching to a later node version. I also tried `CHOKIDAR_POLLING=true` and `FAST_REFRESH=false` but none of them worked.